# Flow & Process Builder - what's the future?

Tags: flow, process-builder

I understand that Process Builder is built on top of the Flow engine. Does anyone have an idea if the Flow feature (of building screens and such) will continue to be around or do you think Salesforce is moving in the direction of having Process Builder replace it?

Answer (score 2):

There are many limitation to both Process Builder and the current Flow Builder. I'm confident that Salesforce would like to people to think Process builder can replace code with clicks, but clearly it's not capable of doing that at this time. The same can be said of Flow Builder. There's much that it simply can't do unless you customize it by embedding things into VisualForce, then modifying pages and controllers.

I think it's safe to say that I don't see native "interview" features of VisualForce (the foundation or origin of Flows) disappearing anytime soon. Plus, since they already exist and are built on Apex, there's no reason for Salesforce to remove them from the "menu" of existing tools, especially considering they'll need to support the many flows out there that were built with those tools for years to come.